# Analyze another file during SonarQube analysis (custom rule)

Tags: java, sonarqube

So, im currently developing a SonarQube Java Plugin with some custom rules.

One of them needs to analyze the Java file for a specific annotation, and if it's missing, it should report an issue UNLESS that annotation is on its superclass.

The problem is that i can't analyze another file (the superclass) DURING the current analysis (on the class).

Is there a way to do this?

Obs: I'm using SonarQube Server 5.6.3 and Sonar Java Plugin 4.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use semantic model to get information about symbols (classes, methods, ...) defined in the project. When you analyze class, you have access to `ClassTree`, so you can test if annotation is present on its superclass like this

```
ClassTree classTree = (ClassTree) tree;
Symbol.TypeSymbol classSymbol = classTree.symbol();
Type superClass = classSymbol.superClass();
SymbolMetadata superClassMetadata = superClass.symbol().metadata();
if (superClassMetadata.isAnnotatedWith("org.acme.MyAnnotation")) {
  //...
}
```

See for example this check [implementation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/cb1baeadb6f9beaab8a04a639a33b90944f73f19/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/ConstructorInjectionCheck.java), which uses the API

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It's gonna help me a lot.